# How to read the last line in terminal and save it in a var using ruby

Tags: ruby, linux

I have this in the terminal

```
   >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Connecting bucket<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  #<Aws::S3::Client:0x00000005219698>
  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Established Bucket Connetion <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  No objects.
```

I want to take the last line, in this case (No object), and save it in a var.
Somebody knows how would be the code in ruby?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to Ruby? Are you running the command from Ruby and want to capture its output? Can you show some code maybe?

Comment: Do you really want to query your terminal application, what it happenes to have displayed in its last line, or do you want to have the last line printed by a certain command?

Answer (score 1):

Capture the output of your command `command_name`, piped through `tail -n 1` to print only the last line, like so:

```
my_var = `command_name | tail -n 1`
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[`tail` docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html):

```
tail(1) - Linux manual page

       -n, --lines=[+]NUM
              output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use
              -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
```